# resolv.conf empty and not using dhcp nameservers from lease

Tags: linux, dhcp, linux-networking, centos7, rhel7

I have a server that doesn't update resolv.conf correctly when networking is restarted. This is a red hat 7 server. It should use the nameservers from dhcp. I checked `/var/lib/dhclient/dhclient--eth0.lease` and there is a line `option domain-name-servers` which has the correct servers to use.

ifcfg-eth0 looks like this:

```
DEVICE=eth0
ONBOOT=yes
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
IPV6INIT=no
MTU=1500
TYPE=Ethernet
NM_CONTROLLED=no
PERSISTENT_DHCLIENT=yes
```

Everything I've read suggests this should be simple and just work. I dont think network manager is a problem. I tried `sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager` and got a message saying the service is not loaded. I added PEERDNS=yes, which defaults to yes any way and made no difference. It's still overwritten with an empty file

```
$ cat /etc/resolv.conf 
options rotate timeout:1
```

I'm not sure what else I could check.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a bug with redhat
https://access.redhat.com/solutions/1433223

updated to the suggested package and my issue went away

Comment: Glad to hear that you found a solution to the issue.  Could you accept your  answer so that your question no longer shows up in the list of unanswered questions?  Thank you.

Comment: Yeah i tried. I got a message saying I need to wait 2 days